# Select rows where multiple column values are in multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select values from a dataframe such as:

```
    Vendor_1   Vendor_2   Vendor_3
0   1          0          0
1   0          20         0
2   0          0          300
3   4          0          0
4   0          50         0
5   0          0          500
```

The values I want to keep from Vendor_1, 2, 3 are all inside a seperate list i.e v_1, v_2, v_3. For example say say v_1 = [1], v_2 = [20], v_3 = [500], meaning I want only these rows to stay.

I've tried something like:

```
df = df[(df['Vendor_1'].isin(v_1)) & (df['Vendor_2'].isin(v_2)) & ... ]
```

This gives me an empty dataframe, is this problem to do with the above logic, or is it that there exist no rows with these constraints (highly unlikely in my real dataframe).

Cheers

EDIT:

Ok so I've realised a fundamental difference with my example and what is actually is like in my df, if there is a value for Vendor_1 then Vendor_2,3 must be 0, etc. So my logic with the isin chain doesnt make sense right, ill update the example df.

So I feel like I need to make 3 subsets and then merge them or something?

Comment: Can you show us the sample data ?Above should work

Comment: @BENY I've added some examples

Comment: @BENY Oh I see you said it should work, unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the data, I guess I should just do some more sanity checks

Comment: @BENY it shouldn't work in above example, as there is no combination that satisfies all requirements

Comment: @liamod this should return empty dataframe with above lists. Try with v_2=[20,30]

Comment: I see why this example should not work, but why in my real dataframe, I think I have the logic wrong

Comment: @IoaTzimas when we talk about the combination (ps : we can do merge) , the combination set should smaller than what he did above , if isin chain with & not work , then we should still empty for combination

Comment: It worked for me with v_2=[20,30]. I would suggest to close the question, probably it's a typo, everything looks fine with the code and logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isin` accepts dictionary:

```
d = {
    'Vendor_1':[1],
    'Vendor_2':[20],
    'Vendor_3':[500]
}

df.isin(d)
```

Output:

```
   Vendor_1  Vendor_2  Vendor_3
0      True     False     False
1     False      True     False
2     False     False     False
3     False     False     False
4     False     False     False
5     False     False      True
```

And then depending on your logic, you want to check for `any` or `all`:

```
df[df.isin(d).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
   Vendor_1  Vendor_2  Vendor_3
0         1         0         0
1         0        20         0
5         0         0       500
```

But if you use `all` in this case, for example, you require that `Vendor_1=1`, `Vendor_2=20`, and `Vendor_3=500` must happen **on the same rows** and you would keep these rows.

Answer (score 1):

The example you're giving should work unless there are effectively no rows that match that condition.

Those expressions are a bit tricky with the parens so I'd rather split the line in two for easier debugging:

```py
mask = (df['Vendor_1'].isin(v_1)) & (df['Vendor_2'].isin(v_2))

# sanity check that the mask is selecting something
assert mask.any()

df = df[mask]
```

Note that you *must* have parens between `&` because of operator precedence rules.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please see my edit, the question is differnt to what was expected

Comment: oh, I'm a bit late but seems you found out the solution. cheers!